# Rails: Render a partial on a single page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4, partials

I am attempting to render a partial on a single page defined within application.html.erb.

This should be specific to the URI http://website.com/ (root or index if you will).

routes.rb

```
has root :to => static_pages#home
```

application.html.erb shows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all",
  "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <%= render 'layouts/homepage_slider' %>
  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to render << layouts/homepage_slider >> on / or my index path only. It needs to be outside for the `<div class=container">` otherwise I would have added it to the static_pages/home file specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap an if/else statement around it.

```
<% if current_page?(root_path) %>
  <%= render 'layouts/homepage_slider' %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= render "layouts/homepage_slider" if current_page?(root_path) %>
```

Comment: Instead of checking for the root path, I would set a variable in the controller of the root path, and check for it in the layout view.   That way you can always toggle the item from other views as well, if later desired.

Comment: +1, Yea I like that method if you use for other views!

Comment: Not using it for other views at the moment. . . however; the controller method seemed to be the best practice. Thank you. Enjoy the weekend! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same challenge when working with **Rails 6** in **Ubuntu 20.04**.

For me, I needed to render a partial in the head tag of my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` to show up on a single page which was the `app/views/products/show.html.erb`.

**Here's how I did it**:

I created the partial in `app/views/shared/_facebook_metatags.html.erb`:

```
<!-- Here's an example of Facebook's Open Graph Markup -->
<!-- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->

<meta property="og:url"           content=<%= "#{@product_url}" %> />
<meta property="og:type"          content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"         content=<%= "#{@product.name}" %> />
<meta property="og:description"   content=<%= "#{@product.short_description}" %> />
<meta property="og:image"         content=<%= "#{@product.image_url}" %> />
```

And then I included it in the head tag of my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` to show up on the `app/views/products/show.html.erb` page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
.
.
.

    <%= render partial: '/shared/facebook_metatags' if params[:controller] == 'products' && params[:action] == 'show' %>
.
.
.
  </head>
</html>
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**